# How to get value from sqlalchemy .execute() method? Python + Sqlalchemy+ MS SQL server

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I wrote a method to get the status of a csv file in a SQL Server table. The table has column named CSV_STATUS, and for the particular csv, I'd like my method to give me the value of the CSV status. I wrote the following function:

```
def return_csv_status_db(db_instance, name_of_db_instance_tabledict, csvfile_path):
table_dict = db_instance[name_of_db_instance_tabledict]
csvfile_name = csvfile_path.name
sql = db.select([table_dict['table'].c.CSV_STATUS]).where(table_dict['table'].c.CSV_FILENAME == csvfile_name)
result = table_dict['engine'].execute(sql)
print(result)
```

**Whenever I print result, it returns: `<sqlalchemy.engine.result.ResultProxy object at 0x0000005E642256C8>`
How can I extract the value of the select statement?**

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [1].

As I understand it, you need to do the following:

```
for row in result:
    # do what you need to do for each row.
```

[1] - https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html